# Are wrappers considered applications?

Tags: discussion, libraries, apps

I went to get an API key for my StackOverflow C++ wrapper, and discovered that this involves registering an "application".

Does the wrapper count as an app?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A library should **take** an app key, not have an app key.  Don't register it.

Also, make absolutely sure your wrapper **demands** an app key at initialization.  You don't want a user locked into the `No Key` request limit erroneously.

If libraries had keys an application abusively using your library (through no fault of yours) could get every application that uses your library blocked.

Comment: Just as an addition, if you are going to test your library, don't use a key (that is what no key is for). However, make sure the final product demands and API key.

Comment: What if I'm testing an app that uses the wrapper.

Comment: @George - During development of a wrapper you don't have to require a key, but every **release** of it should.  This might force an app developer using your wrapper to register for a key earlier than they'd like, but that's the lesser of two evils here.